# Excel macro in worksheet not firing. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA script that fires when a value within a cell range (in this case E7:E10) is selected (from a dropdown).  However, Excel does not seem to give any indication of the macro firing, and I feel it's due to to the header lines.  Here is the header line code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("E7:E10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
```

Is there a way to be able to tell if it's running or not?

Comment: Is that the complete code?

Comment: No, it's the header.  I think it's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Where is this code existing? Most common cause of sheet events not firing is that you've placed the code in a standard module, not the Worksheet module. Either that, or at some point you've disabled events via an `Application.EnableEvents = False` and forgot to reset to `True`.

Comment: It's within the "Microsoft Excel Objects" folder under VBA Project, and it's within the sheet that I'm working on.

Comment: see the second sentence of my previous comment. Are you sure events are enabled?

Comment: And are you sure macros are enabled?

Comment: A search under "Current Project" for Application.EnableEvents yields nothing, so that's unlikely.  And I just set Macros to enable all yet it's not activating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143798/discussion-between-user1623804-and-david-zemens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to be able to tell if it's running or not?

Put a breakpoint or a `MsgBox` call inside the procedure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Address
End If
```

If no message box pops up, then the event didn't fire. Check the value of `Application.EnableEvents` and also ensure macros are enabled.

Note that the `Change` event doesn't fire as a result of recalculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Address = "dropdown cell location" Then
     With Application
       .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       .EnableEvents = False
       .ScreenUpdating = False
     End With
   End If
   'your macro
   If Target.Address = "dropdown cell location" Then
     With Application
       .Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic
       .EnableEvents = True
       .ScreenUpdating = True
     End With
  End If
End Sub
```